# trying to execute a batch file in java

Tags: java, windows, bash, batch-file, native-code

Why doesn't that code work?

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("switchCon.bat");
```

This is the path of that file:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\switchCon.bat
```

This is what the file looks like:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection 2" static 147.8.178.231 255.255.255.0 147.8.176.1 1
```

Comment: What does _doesn't work_ mean?

Comment: What directory context does your application run in (relative to the batch file)?  Is there any errors?

Comment: Use full paths and/or use `cmd /c c:\\path\\to\\file.bat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
Process pr;
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
pr = run.exec("cmd.exe /c C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\switchCon.bat"); 
pr.waitFor();
```

or this:

```
Process pr;
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
pr = run.exec("cmd.exe /c netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection 2" static 147.8.178.231 255.255.255.0 147.8.176.1 1"); 
pr.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specify the full path of the bat file, like this:

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Administrator\Desktop\\switchCon.bat");
```